# How to align list to specific character?

Tags: text-processing, command-line

Is there a command or set of commands that I can use to horizontally align lines of text to an arbitrary character? For example, with a list of email addresses the output would produce a text file with all the '@' characters lined up vertically.

To be successful I believe that a variable number of empty spaces must be added to the beginning of most lines. I do not want separate columns as they take more effort to read (for example, `column -t -s "@" < file.txt`).

Before:

```
123@example.com
456789@example.net
01234@something-else.com
```

After:

```
   123@example.com
456789@example.net
 01234@something-else.com
```

Put differently: can I specify a character to be an anchor point, around which the surrounding text is horizontally centered? My use-case for this is email addresses, to make them easier to scan visually.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple `@` symbols?

Comment: Good question, multiple `@` symbols shouldn't be an issue with email addresses but a user should be able to select which instance of a character per line to be the 'anchor' around which the other text is centered.

Comment: Multiple `@` symbols are allowed in email addresses, e.g. `tom"@brossmann"@example.com`. That's why I asked what should happen if there are multiple `@` symbols :).

Comment: @Zeta Multiple `@` symbols are not allowed in a variety of email services. It's entirely reasonable to expect "normal" emails that fit a tighter standard than the "real" one, unless you're dealing with raw, unfiltered user input, in which case you're more likely to deal with lines with no `@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO Awk. Only `sed` and `column`:

```
column -ts@ file.txt | sed -E 's/([^ ]+)([ ]+) (.+)/\2\1@\3/'
```

Output:

```
   123@example.com
456789@example.net
 01234@something-else.com
```

Now, that I think about, this is almost the same as Sundeep' solution, it just looks shorter / has less calls to `sed`, and it also assumes that `@` happens only once in each line.

Comment: It can be even more short: `column -ts@ input.txt | sed -r 's/([^ ]+)( *)\s\s/\2\1@/'`

Answer (score 11):

At its simplest, you could just print the first field in a suitably large fieldwidth e.g.

```
awk -F@ 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$1 = sprintf("%12s", $1)} 1' file
         123@example.com
      456789@example.net
       01234@something-else.com
```

AFAIK any method that does not assume a specific maximum fieldwidth will require either holding the file in memory or making two passes.

Comment: good one, to get length one can also use `cw=$(cut -d@ -f1 file | wc -L)` and then `awk -v w="$cw" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="@"} {$1 = sprintf("%*s", w, $1)} 1'`

Comment: Testing this against a list of 328 addresses, ten are somehow missing from the output (now 318 lines). For clarity, I ran `awk -F@ '{a[$1] = $2; w = length($1) > w? length($1) : w; next} END {for (i in a) printf("%*s%c%s\n", w, i, FS, a[i])}' INPUT-FILE.txt > OUT.txt`. It did format the remainder nicely, but some data is missing.

Comment: @TomBrossman thanks I just realized it has quite a serious flaw - it will not handle identical name fields - I'm going to delete that one

Comment: The same result, but more concisely `awk -F@ '{printf "%12s@%s\n", $1, $2}' input.txt`

Answer (score 6):

hacky solution, assumes a lot about input text

```
$ # four commas to reduce chance of it affecting actual email address
$ sed 's/@/,,,,@/' ip.txt | column -t -s,,,,
123     @example.com
456789  @example.net
01234   @something-else.com

$ sed 's/@/,,,,@/' ip.txt | column -t -s,,,, | sed -E 's/^([^ ]+)( +)/\2\1/'
     123@example.com
  456789@example.net
   01234@something-else.com
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick Python solution that uses the shortest possible padding length that right-aligns all strings left of the separator:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
fieldsep = '@'
records = [line.rstrip('\n').split(fieldsep, 1) for line in sys.stdin]
col1_len = max((len(r[0]) for r in records), default=0)
for r in records:
    print(r[0].rjust(col1_len), r[1], sep=fieldsep)
```

Usage:

```
python3 align-field.py < data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another GNU **`awk`** + **`column`** solution:

```
awk '{ split($0,a,/ +/,sep); printf "%*s@%s\n",length($1 sep[1])-2,$1,$2 }' <(column -ts'@' file)
```

The output:

```
   123@example.com
456789@example.net
 01234@something-else.com
```

Comment: Could you add a bit about how this one works?

Answer (score 2):

This can work with Bash string manipulation, too.

Bash script (4.x):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -d '' -r -a data <"data.txt"

for ((pos=0, i=0; i<${#data[@]}; i++)); do
    locl=${data[$i]%@*}                         # The local-part.
    [[ ${#locl} -gt $pos ]] && pos=${#locl}     # Determine the lengthiest $locl.
done

for ((i=0; i<${#data[@]}; i++)); do
    email=${data[$i]}
    locl=${email%@*}                            # The local-part.
    domain=${email#*@}                          # The email domain.
    printf '%*s@%s\n' $pos $locl $domain        # Align $locl to the right, at $pos.
done
```

The result:

```
   123@example.com
456789@example.net
 01234@something-else.com
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try `column` with `--table-right`

Here's the input without any formatting:

```bash
$ echo -ne '123@example.com\n456789@example.net\n01234@something-else.com\n'
123@example.com
456789@example.net
01234@something-else.com
```

Here's a first attempt, which does not quite do what we want:

```bash
$ echo -ne '123@example.com\n456789@example.net\n01234@something-else.com\n' |
column --separator @ --table --output-separator @
123   @example.com
456789@example.net
01234 @something-else.com
```

Here's a another attempt. But this time with [the `--table-right 1` option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html#:%7E:text=--table-right) added.
This right-aligns column 1 (columns start at 1) and does what we wanted:

```bash
$ echo -ne '123@example.com\n456789@example.net\n01234@something-else.com\n' | 
column --separator @ --table --output-separator @ --table-right 1
   123@example.com
456789@example.net
 01234@something-else.com
```

Or if you prefer the short options:

```bash
echo -ne '123@example.com\n456789@example.net\n01234@something-else.com\n' |
column -s@ -t -o@ -R1
   123@example.com
456789@example.net
 01234@something-else.com
```